# Proguard does not adapt resources

Tags: obfuscation, proguard

I have on file (entity.tld) with this code:

```
<taglib>
  <tag>
    <name>insertEntity</name>
    <tag-class>pt.caso.ig.data.taglibs.InsertEntity</tag-class>
    <body-content>JSP</body-content>
    <description>       
        Insert entity.
    </description>
    <attribute>
        <name>var</name>
        <required>true</required>
        <rtexprvalue>false</rtexprvalue>
    </attribute>
  </tag>    

</taglib>
```

I ofuscate class: InsertEntity. How adapt resource in file entity.tld???
I use this instrution but don't work

```
-adaptresourcefilecontents **/*.tld
```

Why? Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

The option should work, but if entity.tld is not in a subdirectory, you have to specify the wildcards without a slash:

```
-adaptresourcefilecontents **.tld
```